# Permission required countries for accessing conv.user.storage Actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Through reading `Actions on Google` documentation, I found that to access user storage to store data there, obtaining consent is required in some countries. So my question is where are these countries?? Nothing was specifically detailed so I thought it might have made developers think too.

According to [Actions on Google: Save Data in Conversation oogle:](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data)

> Legal note: Obtaining consent prior to accessing userStorage. Some countries have regulations that require developers to obtain consent from the user before they can access, or save certain information (e.g. personal information) in the userStorage. If you operate in one of these countries and you want to access, or save such information in userStorage, you must use the Confirmation helper to ask consent to the user and obtain the consent before you can start storing such information in userStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain laws like GDPR, applying to European Union countries, which create standards for storing user data. Though other countries may have their own laws. I'm not a lawyer, and getting legal counsel is ideal in discussing legal matters for each country to launch your action.

Otherwise you can set up your action to always get consent ahead of time regardless of location, which isn't a substitute for legal counsel but would fit in the requirement outlined in the documentation.